# I want to select column in r not using " "

Tags: r

for example there is data which have  X,Y,M.
To select column of X I made this function

```
#data
da<-data.frame(x,y,m,coco)

#function
abcde<-function(xxx,d){
  d$xxx
}

abcde(x,da)
```

But there are only empty data....
how can i select column not using ""

Comment: Use the `dplyr` package. It has a `select` function that does this.

Answer (score 1):

### Base R

```r
abcde <- function(xxx, d) do.call(subset, list(xxx, select = substitute(d)))
abcde(mtcars, cyl)
#                     cyl
# Mazda RX4             6
# Mazda RX4 Wag         6
# Datsun 710            4
### ...truncated...
```

Or frankly, just use `subset`:

```r
subset(mtcars, select = cyl)
#                     cyl
# Mazda RX4             6
# Mazda RX4 Wag         6
# Datsun 710            4
### ...truncated...
```

and get the built-in functionality of its `subset=` argument (even if you don't use it often).

### tidyverse

```r
abcde <- function(xxx, d) dplyr::select(xxx, {{d}})
```